# inno setup giving error code 2 with mysql setup

Tags: mysql, inno-setup

I am executing this line in inno setup, but i am getting and exit code 2

```
;Setting root password default root (blank). ex : mypass4u@
Filename: "{app}\mysql\bin\mysqladmin.exe"; \
Parameters: "-u root -e ""update mysql.user set password=PASSWORD('mypass4u@') where user='root';"""; \
StatusMsg: "Setting password root"; \
Flags: runhidden;
```

I get the following message in the debug window

> [11:56:54.387]   -- Run entry -- [11:56:54.392]   Run as: Current user
>   [11:56:54.396]   Type: Exec 
>   [11:56:54.400]   Filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Company\Myapp\mysql\bin\mysqladmin.exe 
>   [11:56:54.405] Parameters: -u root -e "update mysql.user set
>   password=PASSWORD('mypass4u@') where user='root';"
>   [11:56:54.758] Process exit code: 2

What could be causing this error

Comment: Did you try the command on command-line?

Comment: i am installing mysql with my app, which command line are you talking about?

Comment: I mean your command! `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Company\Myapp\mysql\bin\mysqladmin.exe" Parameters: -u root -e "update mysql.user set password=PASSWORD('mypass4u@') where user='root';"`

Comment: The `mysqladmin.exe` does not have any `-e` switch.

Comment: thank you for correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you wanted to use `mysql.exe`, not `mysqladmin.exe`.